# Best way to convert a string of (Javascript)TypedArray to byteArray in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays

I am calling an end point and returning a format of `string` (TypedArray in JavaScript) like the following `[12,44,36,132,22,19,99]`
and want to convert that string back to `byte[]`.

I am using

```
var byteData = Regex.Replace(fileData, @"\[*\]*", "").Split(',').Select(x => byte.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

but just wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this? Thanks guys

```
    protected void downloadFile(string fileKey)
    {
        var url = _apiFileDataUrl + fileKey;
        _filename = fileKey.Split('/').LastOrDefault();
        Log.Information($"Endpoint hit: {url}");

        var requestData = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            RequestUri = new Uri(url)
        };

        requestData.Headers.Add("X-Auth", _x_auth);
        requestData.Headers.Add("x-api-key", _x_api_key);
        //requestData.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

        var results = _client.SendAsync(requestData).Result;
        if (results.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Campaign failure at fileKey {fileKey} \n\n {(int)results.StatusCode}: {results.ReasonPhrase}");
        }

        var fileData = results.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        if (fileData.Length > 0)
        {
            var byteData = Regex.Replace(fileData, @"\[*\]*", "").Split(',').Select(x => byte.Parse(x)).ToArray();
            //var byteData = fileData.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Split(',').Select(x => byte.Parse(x)).ToArray();
            //var dt = DataTableHelper.CsvToDataTable(byteData, "\r\n",'|');
            File.WriteAllBytes(DataFilePath + _filename, byteData);
        }
    }
```

Comment: is this only to replace "[]" by empty string? Regex.Replace(fileData, @"\[*\]*", "")
I cannot imagine a case in which you would send [[]] or something like that to the server. Other than this, the rest looks fine to me

Answer (score 0):

More or less, I would have taken the same path as you did. However, I would not go for the `Regex` path for such a simple task. My code is commented where necessary.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a byte array from the passed TypedArray in javascript.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="jsStringArray">TypedArray in javascript, like [12, 44, 36, 132, 22, 19, 99]</param>
    /// <returns>Byte array created from passed string</returns>
    private static byte[] StringArrayToByteArrayParser(string jsStringArray ) {
        try{

            // // No need to use heavy Regex
            var sb = jsStringArray.Substring(1, jsStringArray.Length - 2);



            // Splits using , then converts into byte array
            return sb.ToString().Split(',').Select(byte.Parse).ToArray(); 
        }
        catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException outOfRange) {
            // Handle etc..
            throw;
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            // Here catch your exceptions throw or handle
            throw;
        }

    }
```

Comment: There is no need to create an instance of `StringBuilder`, as `string` itself has [`Remove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Remove_System_Int32_System_Int32_), which can be used directly on `jsStringArray`. Or, even simpler, you can just use `jsStringArray.Substring(1, jsStringArray.Length - 2)`.

Comment: @Herohtar, I completely missed substring.